# .Net Standard 2.0 Nuget Package with dependency on System.ComponentModel.Annotations throws exceptions only when consumed from .Net Framework project

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

I have a class library that targets `netstandard2.0` and has a dependency on System.ComponentModel.Annotations v4.5. I am building a Nuget package from this class library.

When I consume the package from a .net core project it will work. When I consume the package from a .net framework 4.8 project I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type
>   'System.Array'.
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MinLengthAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value)

Any ideas on what I might need to do here?

Comment: sounds like the implementation of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MinLengthAttribute.IsValid is different on .net framework and netcoreapp. Are you calling this API in your code, or passing in a list to some other System.ComponentModel api or attribute? Try changing it to an array and see if that fixes it. Otherwise you might need to multi-target your class library and use `#if` blocks to compile differently for net framework and netstandard/netcoreapp.

Comment: I'm using a `[MinLength]` attribute on a `List<int>` in my nuget package. In my code that consumes the package, when I validate the object I get the exception. Changing it to an integer array did work but I wanted to keep using a List so to get around the issue I implemented my own MinLength attribute by inheriting from  `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MinLengthAttribute` and overriding the `IsValid` method as this attribute was the only one throwing an exception when consumed from a .Net Framework project.